# How to sum 2 columns within a row of datagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hello guys? i'am working on Windows application form c# and I have 4 Columns in my datagridView, lets say i have 3 rows just like this

```
-------------------------------
|Grade1|Grade2|Average|Remarks|
|------|------|-------|-------|
|    85|    80|   82.5|PASSED |
|    76|    86|     81|PASSED |
|    75|    72|   73.5|FAILED |
-------------------------------
```

Now my question is it possible if i click a compute button it will compute each rows of the Column"Grade1" and Column"Grade2" the computation is

`Grade1 + Grade2 = Average and Average = Average/2`

if it's below 74 the remarks column automatically Have a "FAILED"
if it's above 75 the remarks column automatically Have a "PASSED"

Does anyone have a example code or a link that can help me to do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it possible? Most definitely.  Please post your code blocks so we can further help.

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question you've asked. The question states that you'd like to sum together two column values, and calculate an average of the two columns, then conditionally add remarks -- all within the same row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvGrades.Rows)
    {
        if (decimal.TryParse(row.Cells["Grade1"]?.Value?.ToString(), out decimal Grade1)
            && decimal.TryParse(row.Cells["Grade2"]?.Value?.ToString(), out decimal Grade2))
        {
            var avg = (Grade1 + Grade2) / 2;
            row.Cells["Average"].Value = avg;

            if (avg < 74)
            {
                row.Cells["Remarks"].Value = "FAILED";
            }
            else
            {
                row.Cells["Remarks"].Value = "PASSED";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can enumerate thru all the rows by doing

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
```

you can get or set the value of cells in that particular row by doing

```
row["column name"].Value
```

you can attach a click event to Button.Click (either in code by using `.Click += handler` or do it in the designer)

To assemble all those pieces and come up with a working solution will be your exercise. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I would just add members to the class that is populating the array or list that is used to populate the grid.  The getters for the average and pass/fail fields can handle the logic.